# Subquery with MySql using INSERT

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to update the database, using a script where the ID of a user isn't readily known, so I'm using a subquery to have mysql find the user id (for the `posteruserid` value). This is the SQL query i'm using:

```
INSERT INTO `thread` (`title`, `forumid`, `open`, `replycount`,
 `postercount`, `postusername`, `postuserid`, `lastposter`, 
`dateline`, `visible`, `keywords`) 

SELECT 'IN', 2, 1, 0, 1, 'lemons', `userid` FROM `user` 
WHERE `username` = 'lemons', 'lemons', 1375768440, 1, 'IN';
```

I'm getting a syntax error from the above SQL, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT because of the mismatched column name, I tried using an alias, which still doesn't work

```
INSERT INTO `thread` (`title`, `forumid`, `open`, `replycount`,
`postercount`, `postusername`, `postuserid`, `lastposter`, 
`dateline`, `visible`, `keywords`)

SELECT 'IN', 2, 1, 0, 1, 'lemons',
`userid` AS `postuserid` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = 'lemons',
'lemons', 1375768440, 1, 'IN';
```

Answer (score 0):

column mismatch in insert and select query..column should be same where you are going to insert and from where you are fetching data.

Answer (score 0):

You specify to insert values of 11 columns, but in your `SELECT` statement, you are providing only 7 values. Please provide the value for `lastposter`,`dateline`,`visible`, and `keywords`.